# How to change the output color of text from a file in php

Tags: php

Test.txt file contains some text. How to change the output colour of the text from a file in PHP.

```
Test.txt file
The output should be like this:
This is a | text (The word "text" should be red)
This is another | text (The word "text" should be red)
This is the | best (The word "best" should be red)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change text colour with PHP. You'll have to change the text colour with CSS on your HTML document.

Comment: So how to do it with CSS

Comment: you'll want to use "color: red"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
$text = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$text = str_replace('text',"<span style='color:red;'>text</span>" , $text);
echo $text;
```

For the multiple choice try this

```
$text = file_get_contents('files.txt');
$pattern = ['text','best'];
$replacements = ["<span style='color:red;'>text</span>","<span style='color:red;'>best</span>"];
$text = str_replace($pattern,$replacements , $text);
echo $text;
```

To change the color of string coming after `|` use this

```
$fn = fopen("files.txt","r");
while(! feof($fn))  {
    $line = fgets($fn);
    $needle = substr($line, strpos($line, '|')+1, strlen($line));
    echo $line   = str_replace($needle, "<span style='color:red;'>{$needle}</span>", $line);
   echo '<hr>';
}
fclose($fn);
```

Comment: The word "text" should be red, not the whole context

Comment: Then surround the word text with span: `This is a <span...>text</span>`

Comment: it is not a specific word it changes after | symbol in every line